# Is it possible to programmatically take a screenshot while the computer is locked?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am running Selenium testing overnight (using Java & WebDriver) and would like to take a screenshot when one of the testcases fails. If I use the Robot's `createScreenCapture()` method it only works if the monitor is on, and if I use the Selenium's `getScreenshotAs()` method it doesn't capture any popups or anything that are on top of the window (and often contain the cause of the problem). The `getScreenshotAs()` method does work when the pc is locked so that is what I am currently using. My machines run Windows 7 if that matters.

I adapted this code (found on this site) and am using this currently:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
// Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

This is what I had used previously but it only captures a grey screen with the task bar at the bottom if the pc is locked, but if I'm logged in it works great and captures everything. The problem is I need to have my computer locked overnight and that is when this code needs to run:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
// Get size of screen
Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
// Capture the screen
BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
// Save the screen to to disk
ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, "jpg", new File(fileName));
```

I found some other posts on here asking similar questions but they were all pretty old and didn't quite match my question so I was wondering if any solution given these circumstances was possible?

---

**EDIT:**
When I use the Robot code these are the results. I tried using both Chrome as the browser (ChromeDriver) and Firefox (FirefoxDriver).

**Chrome:**
[image: Screenshot Using Google Chrome]

**Firefox:**
[image]

If I run the Robot version of the screen capture in a class all by itself, just a loop that captures the screen every 5 seconds (Run As > Java Application), it works just fine even with the computer locked, but when I have Selenium run the same code (its Run As > JUnit Test) when a test fails it gives the screenshots above if the pc is locked. I even tried having the Selenium code spawn a new thread to take the screenshot while it did a `Thread.sleep()` but got the same results once the pc was locked.

Comment: This is strange, it captures proper snap, no matter screen is lock or unlock

Comment: Carlos: This is taking place while the computer is locked, but thats a good idea for when the pc isn't locked, thank you

Answer (score 3):

> On a personal desktop, locking screen should not be an issue in capturing screen using AWT Robot.

You can test it using the script [ScreenCapture.java](https://github.com/sighil/RandomScripts/blob/master/ScreenCapture.java)

- Download the java file on to a folder.
- Open cmd in the folder where the file in downloaded
- `javac ScreenCapture.java`
- `java ScreenCapture`

You should be seeing the screenshots getting captured in a loop in the folder. Lock the screen, wait for 5 seconds and then unlock the screen and check the screenshots

> In case of a virtual machine or a remote computer which is accessed via RDP, locking can result in black screenshots.

When a user accesses a desktop normally (without RDP as in case of a laptop or personal computer), user session is set to console. You can see it using the below command.

```
c:\Users\*******\Desktop>query user
USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
>*********              console             1  Active      none   12/18/2018 5:50 PM
```

You can see that the user is connected to the session `console`. In this mode the capture screenshot works perfectly.

But if you are accessing the Desktop using RDP you see the below result.

```
c:\Users\*******\Desktop>FOR /L %N IN () DO (query user
timeout 2)

 // When the screen is locked (RDP closed)
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
>*********                                  1  Disc            .  8/21/2018 12:25 PM
 // When RDP session is active
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
>*********              rdp-tcp#0           1  Active       none  8/21/2018 12:25 PM
```

You can see that when the RDP session is disconnected there is no session that is active. This results in the blank screenshot

> **Solution**

When the RDP closes, you have to activate the `console` session using the below command. This can be done by setting up a scheduled task.

1. Create a batch file with the below content.

   ```
   Tscon 1 /dest:console /v
   ```
2. Open task scheduler by opening `Run` and typing `taskschd.msc`
3. In the `Action menu`, click `Create Task`
4. Give a name to the task
5. Select `Run whether user is logged in or not` check box
6. In the `Triggers` tab, click `New` button
7. Select `On disconnect from user session` and click `OK`
8. In the `Actions` tab, click `New` button
9. Action `Start a program` and point to the location of the batch file and click `OK`
10. Click `OK` to create task

Comment: I am using a personal desktop but the RDP info is still good to know so thank you for that. Unfortunately the code you posted a link to is the exact code I'm trying to use that isn't working, but I think it maybe some kind of compatibility issue with Selenium or something, I added more to my question better explaining what I have tried and the results so I won't rewrite it here but thank you again. Also just fyi, the ScreenCapture.java script takes 1 screenshot and makes a new copy of the same screenshot every 2 seconds with a new filename, but I understood what you were saying.

Comment: I have updated the java file. Thanks for that. I will post another answer detailing debugging strategy involving command line to debug whether the session is active  when the screen is locked

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can take screenshots when pc is locked using the browser -

```
public static String captureScreen(WebDriver driver, String screenName) throws IOException {
    String dest = null;
    try {
        Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000)).takeScreenshot(driver);
        dest = ScreenshotsPath() + "\\" + screenName + ".png";
        ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(), "PNG", new File(dest));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(writeException.toFile());
    }
    return dest;
}
```

My method is returning destination(path to image) as a string because I'm using them in reports. I'm also using AShot() because i want to take a full page screenshot.

Thanks,

Comment: This seems very similar to what I am currently using (TakesScreenshot.getScreenshotAs()), it seems that if it uses the browser it doesn't capture any popups or alerts or things like that. Essentially I want to capture what I would see if the monitor was on. Does your way capture that kind of thing? I would normally just try it and see, but your way involves installing a new .jar and that is kind of tricky here at work (getting permission and all that).

Comment: The method will take screenshot only of the active window of the browser.