# C# - taking screenshots of browser while windows is locked (windows.forms)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, browser

I am making a program in windows.forms, that is controling a browser and frequently takes screenshots of the browser (to check in what state the browser is at different times). However there has been a change of mind of my superior, that the program must now be running on locked pc (windows, using task scheduler). I have solved this problem for several other devices, but I cannot figure out the way for browser to work.

I am trying to use Selenium library and this code:

```
new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArgument("disable-software-rasterizer");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

...

// Capture a screenshot of the web page
Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
// Convert the screenshot to a Bitmap
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(screenshot.AsByteArray));
```

However it seems, that when the PC is locked, the screenshot cannot be made (or maybe the browser itself does not start). I tried "--headless" option, but get blocked by CORS violation. I also tried PuppeteerSharp, but get blocked by DRM (I am working for that company, I am not trying to do anything illegal), tried taking screenshots like this:

```
 Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(s.Bounds.Width, s.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
 {
     using (Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot))
     {

         memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(s.Bounds.X, s.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, s.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
         return screenshot;
     } 
 }
```

but if I understand correctly, Screens (as used in this code) do not exist, while the PC is locked.

Can anyone give me a hand or give me some suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Comment: What your supervisor is asking for **doesn't exist**. To save energy/cpu/ram, the browser doesn't actually do all the rendering work on a locked pc. There's no "screen" to "shot".

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53842821/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-while-the-computer-is-locke?rq=2

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Are you sure there is no workaround? I think that when I tried to start the program in debug, and locked PC during the run of the program, the GetScreenshot() method gave me some pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more of a workaround than anything else but:
The issue can be solved by starting your program manualy, making it wait until the desired time comes (for example with Thread.Sleep()) and locking you PC. When the time comes, the program will execute correctly.
I personaly made my own scheduler inside of my code (since I need to run different configurations one after another).

Answer (score 0):

When you lock your computer, Windows disables GPU rendering and this limits what certain programs can do, like Selenium or in my case SikuliX (which is automation by images). There is **absolutely no way around** this issue.

With my VM I have the following .bat file which I use to keep the VM desktop rendering open:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%i in ('query session ^| findstr "Active"') do set SessionId=%%k
Tscon %SessionId% /Dest:console
```

Comment: I have updated the question. When I start the Program and lock the PC during the run of the program, the program keeps his ability to call driver.GetScreenshot() and finishes properly. Are you absolutely sure there is no way around this?

Comment: Can you try without the argument options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArgument("disable-software-rasterizer");? Why do you want to disable GPU?

Comment: Good idea. Those are the remnants of former memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen() solution. However removing that does not seem to have solved the issue. The same goes for the .bat solution you suggested.

Comment: That's because an Azure VM is always 'on' through my .bat. It's not supposed to be used on a local computer. I've solved issues like yours by using 'DontSleep.exe', keep the computer unlocked and put it in a server room. I'm sorry, there is no way around rendering issues while locking the computer.